# Can all values of types with unit be created with unit?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In *Functional Programming in Scala*, when introducing the concept of the algebra of an API, they propose the following law

```
map(unit(x))(f) == unit(f(x))
```

for some value `x` and function `f`. So far `unit` has been a way to create a unit of parallelism `Par[A]`, but I guess it doesn't have to be here. I anticipate it's the same `unit` as in monads. `map` is what you think it is.

They substitute the identity `id` for `f`

```
map(unit(x))(id) == unit(id(x))
map(unit(x))(id) == unit(x)
```

and finally substitute `y` for `unit(x)`

```
map(y)(id) == y
```

I don't get how they make this last step, unless all possible values of that type can be constructed by `unit`, which doesn't seem right since `Par[A]` is a type alias for a function, along some `object`-level functions, and I'd have thought it trivial to hand-craft some new `Par[A]` functions without `unit`. Given they're talking quite abstractly, my question is how this works generally, not just for their `Par[A]` type.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question correctly, but aren't they just giving a new name to the expression `unit(x)` you can always do that.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez kind of, but my concern is that they're then stating that it's true for _all_ `y`. Yeah I should mention that

Comment: They are not stating that. They are just saying let's call `unit(x)` with the name `y` - Is like saying `val y = unit(x)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez are you certain? they also say "Our new, simpler law talks only about `map`--apparently the mention of `unit` was an extraneous detail". It certainly wouldn't be valid in maths to replace a function call g(x) with an arbitrary parameter y, precisely because the range of g might be smaller than the size of the space

Comment: So making clear I really do not understand anything in the question and in that last comment. And that I am talking about what I used to do in my university when I had to prove things, it was perfectly valid to say look we are going to call all this long expression like `x` so anywhere where that expression appears we will use `x` or anywhere there was an `x` we could replace it with the original expression. That is what referential transparency is all about, that is how lambda calculus is interpreted, that is how basic algebra works.

Comment: You just say hey let's add a new value which is equals to some expression and that is. You can use that in your proofs. I think you are really overthinking it. What the proof says is that for any `x` _(in whatever domain you are)_ then `map(unit(x))(id) == unit(x)` which is the same as `map(y)(id) == y` if and only if `y = unit(x)`. And probably you have already proven `map(y)(id) = y` so the original statement is already true.

Comment: So to make it clear, `y` here is not any arbitrary value like `x`. `y` here is just `unit(x)`, only that. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same book here. If you take a look at the notes, the author says:

> This is the same sort of substitution and simplification one might do when solving an algebraic equation.

Which, in terms of functional programming, means that mapping any value `y` over `id` should be equals to `y`. If we take the concept of referential transparency, which states that:

> An expression is called referentially transparent if it can be replaced with its corresponding value without changing the program's behavior

`y` could represent any value, be it `unit(x)`, `x` or any other value